# R - How to apply a function with all the possible values for a specified argument?

Tags: r, loops, apply

I would like to apply the kmeans function to a dataset.

I run it several times. I increase the number of centers each time. For each run I store the total within sum of square in a vector, and I plot the total within sum of square against the number of clusters like so:

```
# Dummy data
cluster1_x <- rnorm(1000, mean = 3.5, sd = .75)
cluster1_y <- rnorm(1000, mean = 4, sd = 1.13)
cluster1 <- cbind(cluster1_x, cluster1_y)

cluster2_x <- rnorm(1000, mean = 5.2, sd = .75)
cluster2_y <- rnorm(1000, mean = .9, sd = .64)
cluster2 <- cbind(cluster2_x, cluster2_y)

cluster3_x <- rnorm(1000, mean = .68, sd = .86)
cluster3_y <- rnorm(1000, mean = 0.8, sd = 1)
cluster3 <- cbind(cluster3_x, cluster3_y)

df <- rbind(cluster1, cluster2, cluster3)

# To see the dummy clusters
# plot(df, pch = 20) 

# Applying kmeans

# Vector that will be filled with the variance in the clusters
tot.within.sum.square <- rep(NA, 20)

for (nb_center in 1:20){
  tps_start <- Sys.time()
  set.seed(13)
  res.kmeans <- kmeans(df, centers=nb_center, iter.max = 30)
  tot.within.sum.square[nb_center] <- res.kmeans$tot.withinss
  tps_exec <- Sys.time() - tps_start
  print(paste0("Iteration ", nb_center, " : ", tps_exec))
}

plot(1:20, tot.within.sum.square, type = 'b', pch=20)
```

I would like to repeat this process 4 times, each time using a different algorithm. There are 4 different values "Hartigan-Wong", "Lloyd", "Forgy", "MacQueen", so I want to end up with 4 different vectors of length 20, one vector for each algorithm. Each element of a given vector is the value contained in `res.kmeans$tot.withinss`. For example, the 4th element of the vectors is the value corresponding to the total within sum of square of a run of kmeans for 4 centers. I can copy and paste the previous code but I am looking for a more elegant way to achieve the results.

I can somewhat get what I want using this:

```
sapply(algos, function(x) {
  sapply(nb_centers, function(y) kmeans(df, centers = y, algorithm = x))
})
```

but I am not able to store each total.withinss from each iteration of each algorithm in a variable.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You are almost there: ```res <- lapply(algos, function(x) {
  lapply(nb_centers, function(y) kmeans(df, centers = y, algorithm = x))
}); sapply(res, sapply, `[[`, "tot.withinss")```

Comment: Why not in the inner `sapply` call: `kmeans(df, centers = y, algorithm = x)$tot.withinss`?

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm, perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments by @Parfait,

```
tot.withinss <- sapply(algos, function(x) {
  sapply(nb_centers, function(y) kmeans(df, centers = y, algorithm = x)$tot.withinss)
})
```

will do the trick!